# What is wrong with that addArrangedSubview code?

Tags: swift, uistackview

I'm trying to understand how addArrangedSubview is working so I tried with a dummy project. Here's my VC :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var stackOutlet: UIStackView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    let newView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    newView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    stackOutlet.addArrangedSubview(newView)
    stackOutlet.addArrangedSubview(newView2)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

When I launch the app, nothing is appearing. I think I have to set some constraints in the stackView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so for everyone sakes : you need to use this =

```
mapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
mapView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

Comment: What is even mapView in your code?!